# How do I add an ODBC driver to a MAMP environment?

Tags: php, ms-access, mamp

I'm working on something that was built on a PC set-up using php and an ms access database. When I port the app to my MAMP environment, I get

```
Fatal error: Call to undefined function odbc_connect() in /path/to/index.php on line 37
```

line 37 looks like this:

```
return odbc_connect("DRIVER={Microsoft Access Driver (*.mdb)}; DBQ=myfile.mdb",
"ADODB.Connection", "", "SQL_CUR_USE_ODBC");
```

It seems like odbc isn't compiled into the MAMP version of PHP (5). I also tried using PDO, and got similar errors.

Anyone know how to fix this?

Comment: Despite the fact that MS has used "Microsoft Access Driver" as the name of its ODBC driver for Jet data, you're not using Access at all, only Jet. I wish they'd not named it that way because it would save a world of confusion.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You will need to add an ODBC driver like [Actual ODBC](http://www.actualtechnologies.com/) to your machine, that is if your version of PHP had any ODBC functionality complied in, which it should have, but if not you'll need to install a different version with the appropriate support.  I've had good luck with using [MacPorts](http://www.macports.org/) to install PHP.  But note that there are still some functions missing that you may expect you'll have to write wrappers for these functions like so:

```
  if(!function_exists("odbc_fetch_array"))
  {
    function odbc_fetch_array($aResult,$anAssoc=false)
    {
        # Out of rows? Pass back false!
        if(!odbc_fetch_row($aResult)) return false;

        $theRow = array();

          # Build up array
        $theNumFields = odbc_num_fields($aResult);
        $theLimit = $theNumFields+1;
          for($i=1; $i<$theLimit; $i++)
          {
            # WARNING: Starts our index at 0, unlike standard ODBC which starts at 1
              $theRow[odbc_field_name($aResult, $i)] = odbc_result($aResult, $i);
              if(!$anAssoc) $theRow[$i-1] = $theRow[odbc_field_name($aResult, $i)];
        }
        return $theRow;
    }
  }

  if(!function_exists("odbc_fetch_assoc"))
  {
    function odbc_fetch_assoc($aResult)
    {   
        if (DIRECTORY_SEPARATOR == '/') // call local function on MACs
        {
            return odbc_fetch_array($aResult,true);
        }
        else // call built in function on Windows
        {
            return odbc_fetch_array($aResult);
        }
    }
  }
```